# How do I restrict dates on datepicker after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, datepicker

At the moment I have this code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6) {
    $('.date, .datetime, .time').bgIframe();
}

$('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'D M dd, yy', minDate:2, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends});
$('.datetime').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'h:m'
});
$('.time').timepicker({timeFormat: 'h:m'});
//--></script>
```

It works great by I have one thing I would like to add to it.

I use the datepicker so my customers can choose a date when they can pick up an item.

I would like it to blank out the the next two days after it reaches 5.30pm EST.

So at 1pm on Monday I can only select Wednesday onwards. If it is 6pm Monday I can only order Thursday onwards.

Does anyone know how to do this? I couldn't quite figure it out from the API website.

Many Thanks

Peter

Comment: The API offers the minDate and maxDate (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) but you have to code the logic for those specific timeframes. The date object should help make it easier.

Comment: You know client-side dates are based on the users computer settings, right? So there's no way to validate properly unless you get server time...

Comment: Yeah, if you read the comment on the answer I have that all planned out.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per the docs: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

you can set `minDate: 2` depending on what time it is now.

```
var min = 1;
var currentTime = new Date();
if (currentTime.getHours() >=17 && currentTime.getMinutes() >=30){
    min = 2;
}
```

then pass `min` into `minDate`.

as ahren pointed out, though, this will be the user's time, not yours. If you want to find the timezone and adjust from there you can use `getTimeZoneOffset` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Comment: Good thinking. 1+ from me! I will give that a go and let you know how I get on :) I don't know why I didn't think of it like that! Thanks

Comment: I will use PHP to get the EST time and put it in a hidden input. I know that this means users can mess around with the HTML to change the time, but I will have a PHP script verifying the time when the user attempts to add it to the cart. Thanks again